# PHP get the basename(__DIR__) of the parent and not the directory of the included file if used inside an include

Tags: php, directory, basename

My structure is as follows

`public_html/includes/` contains

> ```
> includeMe.php
> ```

the php inside `includeMe.php` is

```
<?php echo basename(__DIR__); ?>
```

`public_html/stuff/` contains

> myPage.php

the php inside myPage.php is

```
<?php include '../includes/includeMe.php'; ?>
```

The output with this code when I visit stuff/myPage.php is

> includes

when I want the output to be

> stuff

since this is the parent of where its being included from.

I know this is the correct behaviour for the code i've used so my question is, what can I echo within `includeMe.php` so that the result when called from the include in `myPage.php` is `stuff` without the need to move the echo to the `myPage.php` itself?

Comment: It looks like this has been already asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105966/php-get-file-directory-of-an-included-file NOTE: if you're visiting url domain/stuff/page.php, you can extract "stuff" from url -> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Maybe that can be helpful in your case

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic I have had a read over and tried the answers in the question you linked to in my includeMe.php but the result is still always includes, not stuff :-/

Answer (score -1):

I tried a few things that worked, even with URL parameters:

```
//includeMe.php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    // /stuff/myPage.php?test=test

echo basename(__DIR__);                          // includes
echo basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); // stuff
echo basename(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])); // stuff
echo basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));    // stuff
```

I think it is noteworthy that this will only work with web request, not on CLI.